# Spring Boot Build Image with Health Check

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, health-check, paketo

I'm building my Docker image using Spring Boot's built in Gradle `:bootBuildImage` task, which is quite convenient, because I don't have to maintain my own `Dockerfile`.

The Gradle task uses the [Paketo Bionic Base Stack](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bionic-base-stack) under the hood and will build a layered Docker image just fine.

Now, some orchestration engines like Docker Swarm (or simply Docker Compose for dev purposes) execute health checks *within* the container. Unfortunately, however, the resulting Spring Boot Docker image doesn't have any health checker tools like `curl` or `wget` installed, so something like

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  springBootApp:
    image: my/springboot/docker-image
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/health"]
```

in `docker-compose.yml` will fail. (I checked that actuators themselves are working fine)

I know that `curl` or `wget` aren't ideal. I was actually hoping that the Paketo Builder would pick up something like this [Health Checker BuildPack](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/health-checker).

Is there a way to configure my `bootBuildImage` Gradle task to include that (or a similar) additional BuildPack?

As mentioned above, I'm looking for an easy to maintain solution and don't want to write my own `Dockerfile` to be able to profit from all the baked in best practices Paketo offers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Health Checkers buildpack hasn't been added to the main builders just yet, but it is fully available to use with your apps.

#### Instructions

1. [Modify your `build.gradle` file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.5/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.examples.buildpacks):

   ```
   tasks.named("bootBuildImage") {
     environment["BP_HEALTH_CHECKER_ENABLED"] = "true"
     buildpacks = ["urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java", "gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/health-checker:latest"]
   }
   ```

   This will set an env variable at build time instructing the health-checkers buildpack to participate. It also tells Spring Boot build tools to append the health-checkers buildpack to the list of Java buildpacks that ship in the builder by default.

   **NOTE** you may want to put in a particular version of health-checkers, that's up to you. It supports standard tag conventions like `:1`, `:1.4`, `:1.4.0` and `:latest` so you can pin to latest major/minor or a specific version.
2. Build.  `./gradlew bootBuildImage`. You'll see the health checkers buildpack included in detection.

   ```
   [creator]     ===> DETECTING
   [creator]     7 of 27 buildpacks participating
   [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates   3.6.0
   [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica 10.0.0
   [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/syft              1.26.0
   [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar    6.6.2
   [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip          5.5.2
   [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot       5.23.0
   [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/health-checker    1.3.1
   ...
   ```
3. Optional. Run `pack inspect <image>` against the produced image. You can see that health checkers has contributed a `health-check` process type.

   ```
   Processes:
     TYPE                  SHELL        COMMAND        ARGS                                               WORK DIR
     web (default)                      java           org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher        /workspace
     executable-jar                     java           org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher        /workspace
     health-check                       thc                                                               /workspace
     task                               java           org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher        /workspace
   ```
4. Run your app. `docker run -d --health-cmd /cnb/process/health-check -p 8080:8080 -e THC_PATH=/actuator/health <image>`.

   The health checker that's used by default is [tiny-health-checker](https://github.com/dmikusa/tiny-health-checker#usage). It has other env variables you can configure but for a Spring Boot app you just need to set the actuator path (unless you have management port set differently, then set `THC_PORT=<management-port>` also.

If you are a Maven user, the process is very similar. Just substitute these instructions for step #1 and then #2 build with `./mvnw spring-boot:build-image`.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <layers>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </layers>
            <image>
                <env>
                    <BP_HEALTH_CHECKER_ENABLED>true</BP_HEALTH_CHECKER_ENABLED>
                </env>
                <buildpacks>
                    <buildpack>urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java</buildpack>
                    <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/health-checker:latest</buildpack>
                </buildpacks>
            </image>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: In the future, that will be sufficient. For now, the buildpack has to be added manually.

Comment: Thank you for this, because it helped me!  Just don't forget to set an environment variable of THC_PORT=<server.port> if you are not running on the default port of 8080.

Comment: Hi @SteveStorck, Should the THC_PORT be added to environment variable of maven-plugin ?

Comment: Yes, it's not in the builders yet. It won't hurt anything to add it either, when it's eventually added it'll be OK if you have it also. We still plan to add this at some point, but hit some snags so it's on the back burner for now.

Comment: @DanielMikusa Why is `--health-cmd` neccessary? It should be part of the Docker image., see [`HEALTHCHECK`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck). Is there any way to do this with Spring Boot Maven Plugin?

Comment: What you're referencing @dur is a Dockerfile command. There is no equivalent in buildpacks, so you need to set that run your run the image. It's possible one will be added to the buildpacks spec in the future, and then we can take advantage of that, but for now it needs set `docker run` or in your K8s config.