# How docker health checks with Spring boot native image?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, graalvm-native-image

Spring boot 3 + graalvm native maven plugin  Building a Native Image Using Buildpacks.

mvn -Pnative spring-boot:build-image

then docker run this image, in this container, cannot use curl or wget to health check,

```
exec: "curl": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Entering this container, I found that except for the "native-image" command, all other commands are not available.

is there any solution？

is there any solution？

Comment: Can you provide full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Find an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75885269/spring-boot-build-image-with-health-check#:%7E:text=The-,Health,-Checkers%20buildpack%20hasn%27t)

For me, this will solve my problem

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <buildpacks>
                        <buildpack>urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image</buildpack>
                        <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/health-checker</buildpack>
                    </buildpacks>
                    <env>
                        <BP_HEALTH_CHECKER_ENABLED>true</BP_HEALTH_CHECKER_ENABLED>
                    </env>
                </image>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

docker compose.yaml:

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "/cnb/process/health-check"]
environment:
  THC_PATH: /actuator/health
  THC_PORT: 8080
```