# Spring Boot Buildpacks with HealthCheck is breaking Native Image build process

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm, buildpack

I am trying to add healthchecks to my Spring Boot application while using Buildpacks as suggested in [Spring Boot Build Image with Health Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75885269/spring-boot-build-image-with-health-check).

My pom.xml configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <builder>dashaun/builder:tiny</builder>
            <name>${docker-image-name}</name>
            <env>
                <BP_HEALTH_CHECKER_ENABLED>true</BP_HEALTH_CHECKER_ENABLED>
            </env>
            <buildpacks>
                <buildpack>urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java</buildpack>
                <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/health-checker:latest</buildpack>
            </buildpacks>
        </image>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And my docker-compose.yml configuration:

```
  catalog-service:
    image: sivaprasadreddy/catalog-service
    container_name: catalog-service
    environment:
      - THC_PATH=/actuator/health
      - THC_PORT=8081
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "/cnb/process/health-check" ]
      start_period: 30s
      interval: 5s
      retries: 10
```

Now when I build the docker image using JVM build (`mvn spring-boot:build-image`) and run the container using docker-compose with the above-mentioned health check, it works fine.

**Problem:**
The problem is when I try to build a GraalVM Native using `mvn -Pnative spring-boot:build-image`, it is not building a native image, instead it is building a regular jvm based image.

When I remove `<buildpacks>...</buildpacks>` config, it is properly building native image.

Should I include any additional buildpacks to support building native image or am I misconfiguring anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a different set of buildpacks required to run when you want to build a native image app. Because you're including a `<buildpacks>` block, you're specifically saying "use this set of buildpacks". That overrides the default selection, which would normally handle automatically selecting the right set of buildpacks (i.e. standard JVM or GraalVM).

If you want to build a native image app, you'll need to switch the `<buildpacks>` block out, like this.

```
            <buildpacks>
                <buildpack>urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java-native-image</buildpack>
                <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/health-checker:latest</buildpack>
            </buildpacks>
```

Then make sure that you run `./mvnw spring-boot:build-image -Pnative` with the `native` profile enabled. That's required as well.

See [the instructions in this sample for an example](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/samples/tree/main/java/native-image/spring-boot-native-image-maven).

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. Configuring this triggered the native image build. However, it failed with error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building. The classes that are being initialized are com.sun.beans.introspect.ClassInfo, com.sun.beans.introspect.MethodInfo, etc.

Comment: Looks like the problem is not with buildpacks configuration. I am getting the same error while building native image even with default configuration.

Comment: One observation is this issue happens only when the app uses Thymeleaf layout or webjars.

Comment: Yes, that is an issue with your app. When you can native image build locally, try again with buildpacks and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that for some reason `native-image` is unable to create a native image when using buildpacks. As a result, it creates a fallback file which requires a JVM to run (see [Native Image Compatibility Guide](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/metadata/Compatibility/#features-incompatible-with-closed-world-assumption)):

> If the native-image builder is unable to optimize an application at build time, it generates a so-called “fallback file” that requires a Java VM to run.

You could try to disable the fallback image and see if that works:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${native.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <fallback>false</fallback>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If not, it may reveal the root cause for the failure.

Comment: Tried to disable fallback, but it still continues to build JVM based image.